# Swift Passing array of dictionary to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, swift, dictionary

I am trying to pass swift array of dictionaries to the NSMutableArray. But I am getting error "Cannot convert value of type [[String : Anyobject?]] to expected argument type NSMutableArray". Below is the code:

```
   var ary : [[String:AnyObject?]] = []
   var mutableDictionary = [String: AnyObject?]()

   for c in buffer {
       mutableDictionary.updateValue(c.Name, forKey: "name")
       mutableDictionary.updateValue(c.Number, forKey: "phoneNumber")
       mutableDictionary.updateValue(c.id, forKey: "id")
       ary.append(mutableDictionary)
   }
```

Now passing this "ary" to the Objective C method as a NSMutableArray!

```
Manager.sharedInstance().List(ary)
```

Comment: Try `Manager.sharedInstance().List(ary as! NSMutableArray)`.

Comment: No it crashes with this as casting from [[string : anyobject?]] to nsmutablearray always fails

Comment: `NSMutableDictionary` can't contain optionals, and neither can `NSMutableArray`.  You have to drop the optional on `AnyObject`.

Comment: @Avi yay! thanks Worked!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replica of your issue:

```
    var ary : [[String:AnyObject]] = []
    var mutableDictionary = [String: AnyObject]()
    var mutableArray:NSMutableArray!

    for _ in 0...4 {
        mutableDictionary.updateValue("adsf", forKey: "name")
        mutableDictionary.updateValue("dsf", forKey: "phoneNumber")
        mutableDictionary.updateValue("sdfd", forKey: "id")
        ary.append(mutableDictionary)
    }

    mutableArray =  NSMutableArray(array: ary)
```

Removing the optional did the trick!

Comment: Thanks alot! worked but what problem does it cause with optional? anyidea

Comment: The only explanation I have is that: _"NSMutableArray doesn't hold optionals"_. I hope someone with better and deep explanation will come and explain us here.

Answer (score 1):

// try like this

```
Manager.sharedInstance().List(NSMutableArray(array: ary as! NSArray))
```

Comment: No it crashes with this as casting from [[string : anyobject?]] to nsmutablearray always fails

Comment: do one thing instead of this statement  (var ary : [[String:AnyObject?]] = []) you can take like this var ary: [AnyObject] = []

Comment: and try above solution